# How using Angular 14 trackBy Function with strict-mode: true?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the problem to use trackBy in angular 14 with strict-mode: true,

This is the code (which works like charme in strict-mode: false)

app.component.html:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; index as i; trackBy: trackByFn">
  {{ i + 1 }} {{item.name}}
</div>


<br>

<button (click)="addSomething()">Load Data</button>
```

app.components.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

interface DemoArray {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'angular-sandbox';

  public items: DemoArray[] = [
    { id: 0, name: 'Apfel' },
    { id: 1, name: 'Mango' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Birne' },
  ];

  public addSomething(): void {
    this.items = [
      { id: 0, name: 'Apfel' },
      { id: 1, name: 'Mango' },
      { id: 2, name: 'Birne' },
      { id: 3, name: 'Kiwi' },
      { id: 4, name: 'Mandarine' },
      { id: 5, name: 'Banane' },
    ];
  }

  trackByFn(item) {
    return item.id;
  }
}
```

When using strict-mode:true and changing the trackByFn to:

```
  trackByFn(item: { id: any }) {
    return item.id;
  }
```

VSCode says:

Type '(item: { id: any; }) => any' is not assignable to type 'TrackByFunction'.ngtsc(2322)
app.component.ts(8, 44): Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Strict mode in Angular enables below things

- Enables strict mode in TypeScript
- Strict angular compiler `strictTemplates`, `strictInjectionParameters`, and `strictInputAccessModifiers`
- Reduced bundle size budget

Because `strictTemplates` types on templates are strictly checking its types, like how it does in typescript.

Now in this case, `trackBy` we are passing `TrackByFunction`. Currently written `trackByFn` does not follow the type `TrackByFunction`.

```
interface TrackByFunction<T> {
  <U extends T>(index: number, item: T & U): any
}
```

So the `trackByFn` function should follow the `TrackByFunction` interface signature.

```
trackByFn(index: number, item: { id: any }) {
   return item.id;
}
```

Comment: I will check your code THX

Comment: @HOST-X my code is no different than yours, I wrote this answer to explain, why it didn't work. And why it fixed this way. Thanks :)

Comment: Ha ha, That's cool. Maybe you have free capacity, so I can book you for an Angular project which is in the pipeline?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the Function to:

```
  trackByFn(index: any, item: { id: any }) {
    return item ? item.id : undefined;
  }
```

does the trick for me!